# Change pubDate in rss feed in another format

Tags: rss, date, feed, validation, timestamp

In the default wordpress rss feed the element `<pubDate>` is

`<pubDate><?php echo mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', true ), false ); ?></pubDate>`

and gives a result of `<pubDate>Tue, 12 May 2020 12:39:03 +0000</pubDate>`

how can i change this line to give a result of `<pubDate>12/05/2020 12:39:03 +0000</pubDate>` (d/m/Y) or `<pubDate>12-05-2020 12:39:03 +0000</pubDate>` (d-m-Y)  but to be valid with RFC-822 ?

I tried many variations `<pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('r', get_the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s')); ?></pubDate>` or `<pubDate><?php echo get_post_time( 'd/m/Y H:i:s O', true ); ?></pubDate>` but they dont validate.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this by customizing the feed:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

This way you can make your own template for a feed, and alter the pubDate to your needs.

Comment: I already created my own template for a feed, but i can't change the format of the date to be valid. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you validating your feed, and what is the error you are seeing?

Most likely you simply need to wrap the time in CDATA. Looking at an existing feed from wordpress you can see the example:

Try replacing your `pubDate` with the CDATA version and see if it validates!